# phpstorm working on a branch without touching other branches

Tags: git, branch, phpstorm, git-branch, gitignore

I'm new to git and branches, so maybe i just make a stupid mistake.

I have 2 branches "master" and "sockets". If i edit files in a branch and checkout to the other branch, the previous files are marked for committing.

How can i work on a branch without touching the other branch? do i need a second working directories?

Regards

**Update:**
I ignored a file in .gitignore and phpstorm, but if i edit the ignored file and change the branch it detects the ignored file as edited and wants to commit it. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to checkout the branch you want to work on :

`git checkout sokcets`

Then you make your changes on that branch, and either `git commit`, `git stash` or discard those changes :

```
edit some files
git add something
git commit
```

Then you can checkout another branch :

`git checkout master`

Comment: ok, thanks works! but can you also answer the updated question?

Comment: @user2834172 `.gitignore`, like any other file, should be added to the repository and committed.

Comment: @user2834172 If the ignored file name appears in `.gitignore` of only one of the branches, in the other branch it would be treated as a regular untracked file.

Comment: it's in both .gitignores, the thing is i have pushed this file once, but because in there are sensitive settings i wanna edit it without commiting it, so i added it everywhere to ignore but doesnt work..

Comment: Make sure the `.gitignore` file is in the same folder as the ignored file, and that it's actually called `.gitignore` and not `.gitignore.txt` (which might happen if you created it in Notepad).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58821/discussion-between-user2834172-and-eran).

Comment: i added now also the `.gitignore` in the same folder doesn't help. Here you can see the problem in action at [screenr](https://www.screenr.com/gQXN)